How to complete Oozie build for Hadoop 3.3.6?
I am encountering the problems others have had building Oozie against Hadoop 3.3.6.  Our data wizards have been using 3.3.6 for a year or so and I doubt they would want to regress to an earlier version.
If anyone can offer any useful suggestion it would be of great help as we are not very experienced in DEVOPS and are learning as we go.  Unfortunately, my experience of Apache anything is that (usually) the software far exceeds the documentation which accompanies it.
Hadoop 3.3.6
Ubuntu 22
Oozie 5.2.1
bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests -Phadoop-3 -Dhadoop.version=3.3.6 -Dhadoop.majorversion=3 -e
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project oozie-tools: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/root/BUILD/oozie-5.2.1/tools/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/tools/TestECPolicyDisabler.java:[50,71] getErasureCodingPolicy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in org.apache.oozie.tools.TestECPolicyDisabler.MockDistributedFileSystem cannot override getErasureCodingPolicy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
[ERROR]   return type org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.SystemErasureCodingPolicies.ReplicationPolicy is not compatible with org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ErasureCodingPolicy
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project oozie-tools: Compilation failure
/home/root/BUILD/oozie-5.2.1/tools/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/tools/TestECPolicyDisabler.java:[50,71] getErasureCodingPolicy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in org.apache.oozie.tools.TestECPolicyDisabler.MockDistributedFileSystem cannot override getErasureCodingPolicy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
  return type org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.SystemErasureCodingPolicies.ReplicationPolicy is not compatible with org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ErasureCodingPolicy
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/home/root/BUILD/oozie-5.2.1/tools/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/tools/TestECPolicyDisabler.java:[50,71] getErasureCodingPolicy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in org.apache.oozie.tools.TestECPolicyDisabler.MockDistributedFileSystem cannot override getErasureCodingPolicy(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) in org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
  return type org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.SystemErasureCodingPolicies.ReplicationPolicy is not compatible with org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ErasureCodingPolicy
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute (TestCompilerMojo.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

